# How to 'json cat' a log file where each row is a separate json structure "{ ... }" and print a particular field?

Tags: json, shell

We use json format in log files, where each line is a separate json structure/entity. I need a way to effectively cat a batch of these files and output a named field that can then be piped through other processes, similar to `cat 2024-01*.log | cut -d "," -f 2 | sort | uniq -c` (for CSV format text log files).

Have only tried importing the json log file into Excel after making the file look like a single json array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jq` command:
basic [info here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8sOmEe2SDg)
cat file.json | jq [options]

To get the js equivelent of `Object.values()` you can use `jq '.[]'`
To get a specific property from each object you can use `jq '.[].property'`
ethc etc.
Here is a tldr documentation of jq

```
 - Execute a specific expression (print a colored and formatted JSON output):
   {{cat path/to/file.json}} | jq '.'

 - Execute a specific script:
   {{cat path/to/file.json}} | jq --from-file {{path/to/script.jq}}

 - Pass specific arguments:
   {{cat path/to/file.json}} | jq {{--arg "name1" "value1" --arg "name2" "value2" ...}} '{{. + $ARGS.named}}'

 - Print specific keys:
   {{cat path/to/file.json}} | jq '{{.key1, .key2, ...}}'

 - Print specific array items:
   {{cat path/to/file.json}} | jq '{{.[index1], .[index2], ...}}'

 - Print all array items/object keys:
   {{cat path/to/file.json}} | jq '.[]'

 - Add/remove specific keys:
   {{cat path/to/file.json}} | jq '. {{+|-}} {{{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", ...}}}'
```

Comment: The jq command does the job admirably, so can zcat a bunch of gz compressed json files through jq, extract the fields I need then pipe the output through other commands to aggregate/summarise them. Exactly what I need to do.